# SSL module is missing when installing Python packages in QGIS with the new osgeo4w installer

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo4w

I'm trying to install a third party python package in a QGIS plugin with the following code:

```py
import sys
import platform
import subprocess
try:
    import matplotlib
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print('installing matplotlib')
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        subprocess.call([sys.exec_prefix + '/python', "-m", 'pip', 'install', 'matplotlib'])
    else:
        subprocess.call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'matplotlib'])
```

This code snipped have worked previously but with the new(?) OSGeo4W package it fails since the SSL module is not loaded? The error message looks like this:

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
> however the ssl module in Python is not available.
>
> WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL
> because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/

Is it a bug or some intended change?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: No, now I guide my users of the plugin to manually install instead :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, but I did a lot of things, and am not sure what all contributed to the solution.  However, I think the following step is all you need to do.

Use the osgeo4w setup (advanced install, and in administrator mode) to install the openssl module.
[image]
I ran everything in the advanced installer that was on by default, but I think you could specify only the OpenSSL package.

Comment: Hi, no the openssl module did not solve it for me (I think it was installed by default, or it at least installed now but it doesn't work for me :( )

Comment: same for me, but I did with a non-admin user.